# Calling a function that takes std::function as an argument

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, std-function

I have the following code that implements a callback. I would like the callback to take some arguments but can only get it to compile with no arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template<typename TDeserialisable>
class Images;
class Analyze;

class X
{
    void operator()(...) {}
};

/** Interface for serialising/deserialising types defined by TDeserialisable */
template<typename TDeserialisable>
class IDeserialisable
{
public:
    virtual void deserialise(std::function<void()> callback) = 0;
    virtual void deserialise(std::function<void(IDeserialisable<TDeserialisable>&)> callback) = 0;
};

class Analyze
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        // deserialise
    }

    void operator()(Images<Analyze>& images)
    {
        // deserialise
    }
};

template<typename TDeserialisable>
class Images : public IDeserialisable<TDeserialisable>
{
private:
    virtual void deserialise(std::function<void()> callback)
    {
        callback();
    }

    virtual void deserialise(std::function<void(IDeserialisable<TDeserialisable>&)> callback)
    {
        callback(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Analyze a;
    Images<Analyze> images;

    // calls the first overload
    static_cast<IDeserialisable<Analyze>&>(images).deserialise(a);

    // how do I call the second overload of deserialise?

    return 0;
}
```

How do I call the second overload of deserialise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the input parameter type as a function parameter to the `std::function` `template` type.  Something like:

```
std::function<void(Analyze&, Images<Analyze>&)> mf_p = Analyze::operator();
```

Comment: I don't follow. Please can you elaborate.

Comment: @ksl edited answer to create pointer to your `operator()` member function

Comment: I still don't get it. That gives the compiler error 'call to non-static member function without an object argument'. Also, I don't see how that enables me to call the 2nd overload of deserialise.